# What are "oracle results"?

Tags: logic, computational-complexity, computability

I was reading [this poll](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/papers/poll.pdf) about the notorious *P vs NP* problem. Particularly, at the 6th page, *William Gasarch* says that *we have made some progress in understanding which types of proofs do not work in trying to solve the P vs NP problem*; specifically he mentions the "oracle results".

From the name I can guess a little bit what type of proof would be a "oracle result", but what exactly is it? How does it usually proceed? Is it a serious type of proof? All these questions assuming that this is really a type of ("serious") mathematical proof.

Comment: An [Oracle machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine) is the mathematical equivalent of the original Greek Oracle at Delphi - it "mysteriously answers the un-answerable". That's helpful, but even oracles have their limits.

Comment: I've retagged - in particular, "proof theory" is not the general theory of proofs, but rather [a specific subfield of mathematical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_theory).

Answer (score 18):

Despite the odd-sounding name, oracles are indeed part of serious mathematics.

An oracle machine is a Turing machine equipped with some infinite binary string, the bits of which it can query during its operation. There are two things that I've heard the phrase "oracle result" or "oracle proof" used to describe:

The first is the use of oracle machines to prove results in computability theory. This does not mean that the oracle machine provides the proof; rather, that the proof is gotten by, among other things, proving some facts about oracle machines and then using them, that is, that oracle machines are *relevant mathematical objects* to the problem being solved. For example, the existence of minimal Turing degrees below $0''$ has a proof which involves proving things about certain oracle machines, as well as a proof which does not. **This is not what Gasarch means, but it's worth being aware of.**

The second - and relevant - meaning is, results which are *relativized* to an oracle. For any fixed oracle $A$, we can define the complexity classes $P^A$ and $NP^A$: $P^A$ is the class of problems solvable *by a machine with $A$ as an oracle* in polynomial time, and similarly for $NP^A$. Another instance of relativized definitions in complexity theory is [the polynomial time hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy), where each successive level consists of problems solvable in polynomial time by machines given a set from the previous level as an oracle.

Now, often in computability theory, theorems *relativize*: if something is true about two computability-theoretic classes, it's true of those same classes relative to any oracle. For instance, it's a standard result (the Friedberg-Muchnik theorem) that there are incomparable c.e. degrees; and the proof immediately shows in fact that for any set $A$, there are incomparable degrees which are c.e. *relative to* $A$.

By contrast - and this is what Gasarch refers to - this kind of relativization **does not** tend to hold in complexity theory! In particular, Baker, Gill, and Solovay proved that:

- There is an $A$ such that $P^A=NP^A$.
- There is a $B$ such that $P^B\not=NP^B$.

So however, $P$ vs. $NP$ is resolved, the proof will have to depend specifically on the properties of the *actual* $P$ and $NP$; trying to relativize it to arbitrary oracles will necessarily break something.

Now, Gasarch says that this result is useful in understanding what techniques can't be used to solve $P$ vs. $NP$. The reason for this is that we can show that a number of techniques *are* relativizing: e.g. if you could use them to separate $P$ and $NP$ (or prove them equivalent), you could also use them to separate $P^A$ and $NP^A$ (or prove them equivalent) for any oracle $A$. By GBS, this means those proof techniques **cannot** be used to resolve $P$ vs. $NP$.

There are other barriers to answering $P$ vs. $NP$ as well, which are of a similar flavor - in particular, the "natural proofs" barrier of Razborov and Rudich. But the relativization barrier was the first major barrier discovered, and by far the simplest one to state and prove.

Comment: @nbro Oracle machines lead to the notion of *relative computability*, or *Turing reducibility*: $A\le_TB$ if an oracle machine with oracle $B$ can compute $A$. (There are also e.g. polynomial-time versions of Turing reducibility, etc.) If $A\le_TB$ and $B\le_TA$, we say $A\equiv_TB$ (for instance, every set is $\equiv_T$ its complement); $\equiv_T$ is an equivalence relation, and its equivalence classes are the *Turing degrees*, and are partially ordered by "$\le_T$" in a natural way. A c.e. (computably enumerable) set is the domain of a partial computable function. (cont'd)

Comment: A c.e. *degree* is a Turing degree which contains a c.e. set. Finally, two degrees - c.e. or otherwise - are *incomparable* if neither is $\le_T$ the other. Basically, what Friedberg and Muchnik showed was: there are two computable functions, $f$ and $g$, such that knowing the domain of $f$ doesn't help you figure out the domain of $g$, and vice versa.

Comment: This answer is a very useful resource!  re: "Oracle machines are relevant mathematical objects to the problem being solved", in a very reductionist sense, could this be said to be a form of subjectivity based on constraints, or am I completely misunderstanding.  (I find this subject mind-bendingly complex, and as I am not so smart, I try to chip away at it a little at a time when I can:)

Comment: @nbro I just came across this question again. Is there more explanation I could add that would be helpful?